# Multiple divs with same class name need individual operation

Tags: jquery, function

I am currently trying to create an effect that will involve a panel expanding when the appropriate link is hovered. As you hover over the link im using jquery to change the absolute position to make it slide up but i have duplicates of the same panel. How can I code this so that when each link is highlighted it only activates the slide for its own panel and not all the duplicates which share same div classes. Basicially need to localise the code to only run per each panel, as it is now each link activates all the slides

```
    $(function(){
        $(".expandLink").hover(function(){
            $(".hiddenContent").stop(true, false).animate({ top: "110px" }, 150);
        }, function() {
            $(".hiddenContent").stop(true, false).animate({ top: "185px" }, 150);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to select it with `find` like this:

```
$(function(){
    var allContent = $('.hiddentContent');
    var stopAnimation = function() {
        allContent.stop(true, false);
    };

    $(".expandLink").hover(function(){
        stopAnimation();

        $(this).find(".hiddenContent").animate({ top: "110px" }, 150);
    }, function() {
        stopAnimation();
        $(this).find(".hiddenContent").animate({ top: "185px" }, 150);
    });
});
```

Comment: I think find will select all elements with the same class name too inside the parent container.

Comment: @SheikhHeera "Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element." http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: Yes, that's right and if there is more than one descendants then it will be applied on both.